# How to add JSON data to the card and display to the end user

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

```js
var SendInfo = {
  "dataKey": "1013"
};
console.log(SendInfo);

$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'http://34.201.147.118:3001/getData',
  data: JSON.stringify(SendInfo),
  contentType: "application/json",
  traditional: true,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //console.log(Data[0]);
    var x = $("p:nth-child(0)").append(data[0]);
    console.log(x);

  }
});
```

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 40%;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="container" id="101">
    <h4><b>AcquiringDivision</b></h4>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the success function I want to add all data which is in the console to my card which I created but I am getting some errors here is my JSON data which I am getting in my console.

How to add data to my card using jQuery?

```
{Data: {…}}
Data:
AcquiringDivision:""
EndDate:"20-05-2019"
Excl:"yes"
Format:"mp4"
Language:"English"
 Media:""
Owner:"bb"
ProductID:"1013"
StartDate:"20-05-2018"
```

Comment: Just use `data.Data` then. You're receiving an object called `Data` who contain what you want

Answer (score 3):

Since the data `{Data: {…}}` is Object, you should not use it as Array `data[0]`.

The structure of data is {Data: value}, so you should retrieve Data by `var realData = data.Data;`

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://34.201.147.118:3001/getData',
        data: JSON.stringify(SendInfo),
        contentType: "application/json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var realData = data.Data;
            console.log(realData);
            setData(realData);

        }
    });
```

To add data, you can use jQuery, there's example below:

```
function setData(data){
    $('.card b').text(data.AcquiringDivision);
    // ...and so on    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand. You can use `handlebars.js` to achieve this .
I have taken a different example and it will work in your case too

[**Handlebars.js**](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

**Handlebars Template**

```
 <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
 {{#data}} 
<div class="card">
 <div class="container" id="101">
 <h4><b>AcquiringDivision</b></h4>
   <p>{{AcquiringDivision}}</p>
 <h4><b>End Date</b></h4>
   <p>{{EndDate}}</p>
 <h4><b>Excel</b></h4>
   <p>{{Excl}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
 {{/data}} 
</script>
```

**JS**

```
  var source = $("#some-template").html(); 
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

 var data = { 
   data: [
        {
         AcquiringDivision:"",
         EndDate:"20-05-2019",
         Excl:"yes",
         Format:"mp4",
         Language:"English",
         Media:"",
         Owner:"bb",
         ProductID:"1013",
         StartDate:"20-05-2018"}
         ]
       }; 


 $('body').append(template(data));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfuwjk3m/)

Comment: thanks a lot for support
i am getting in line 29 handlebar is not defined

Comment: @VenkateshMuthyala You should place Handlebars.js script in your head tag .
please do that .
If that doesn't solves your problem let me know.

Comment: if you can plese edit your answer i have just copy pasted your code just see the working  and ui

Comment: Check the answer and fiddle once again. I have updated both of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172879/discussion-between-shivank-verma-and-venkatesh-muthyala).